# nginx subdirectory configuration endless redirect

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I am running nginx to serve a static site (angular) with a proxy_pass to a node js server on an `/api` subdirectory. That is working fine.

I am now trying to also add a similar proxy_pass on the `/blog` subdirectory that redirects to a locally running wordpress instance (running in a docker container). However, when I try to reach `/blog` from outside, it immediately redirects me to `<same-domain>/blog/wp-admin/install.php` and this is done in a loop until the browser gives up.  If I do a `curl -I localhost:8000/wp-admin/install.php` on the server itself, it does return actual response and not redirect to the same URL, so I am pretty sure the nginx config is the problem.

Via the `docker-compose.yml` for wordpress, I am setting `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` properly to include `/blog` in the URL, as necessary.

I looked everywhere and tried everything I could find but I cannot resolve this issue. Since I have very little experience with nginx, I would appreciate some help in fixing or diagnosing the issue. Here is the nginx config file (the domain name has been replaced with `<some-domain>`):

```
...

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name <some-domain>;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<some-domain>/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<some-domain>/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    expires $expires;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name <some-domain>;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location /blog/ {
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
        proxy_redirect          off;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no redirects in your nginx configuration. You need to look for the problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix the problem. Actually, there were several issues:

1. The `proxy_pass` must have a slash at the end, or else it passes the `/blog` part to the wordpress server (or so it seems) and it doesn't know what to do with it:

   ```
   proxy_pass              http://localhost:8000/;
   ```
2. Since I am using `https`, wordpress needs to be passed the header `X-Forwarded-Proto` with the correct protocol. This makes it use `https` and can actually be seen in the `wp-config.php` that the docker container auto-creates. So I added this to the config too:

   ```
   proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   ```

So far this makes the blog somewhat work. However, there is one more issue.

3. Wordpress still assumes it is occupying a server by itself, so the links inside the admin area are not prepended with `/blog`. I found the solution for this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52606237/988858) to another question on StackOverflow. However, to avoid making manual changes inside the container itself, which might get overwritten at a later point (and make a subsequent deployment error-prone), I managed to add that code to the `docker-container.yml` too, along with the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` variables, so it looks like this:

   ```
   ...
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: <some-user>
     <other-stuff>
     WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
      define('WP_HOME','https://fitganizer.com/blog');
      define('WP_SITEURL','https://fitganizer.com/blog');
      $$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  $$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   ```

   Note the double `$$` - apparently this is the way to escape `$` in the `docker-compose.yml`. Otherwise it gets removed when the container is started.

Now it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your `wp-config.php` file and add the following lines:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://yourdomain.com/blog');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://yourdomain.com/blog');
```

WordPress tries to autodetect your domain based on the request it gets. However, when it runs behind a reverse proxy, the request doesn't contain correct information for autodetection. This causes WordPress to enter into infinite redirect loop.

Comment: I am doing that, in the `docker-compose.yml`, and the `wordpress` image picks up those and adds them automatically to the file. I have verified that `wp-config.php` contains those lines by viewing the file inside the docker container. Although I am not sure what protocol should be used in these variables - `http` or `https`?

Comment: You need to use `https` protocol, since that is how your `/blog` is served with.

Comment: I tried both protocols. The result is the same.